# Stored Procedure inserts zero records into Table

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, insert, troubleshooting

I have a task to write a Stored Procedure that essentially needs to fetch data from different tables, and join it to insert it into a single table that has bunch of calculated fields in it.

These calculated fields is a basic formula to tell how much money a client location is making. They're called Hold Per Day. The table also contains a few other calculated fields that my company internally uses called "LocationShare" you will see.

I store the Hold Per Day (HPD) fields in temp tables as the calculation can be a burden on running and is a bottleneck for the procedure, then join them at the end of the proc.

The problem that I am facing, is that everytime I run and test the procedure, it runs and calculated the data for the HPD_Temp tables, as well as the LocationShare table, but no records are brought back to insert into the table at the end. The Execution Plan shows **0** as the amount of rows inserted.

You can see here that filtering the data down by an *X* amount of days brings back zero records for the #HPD_Temp3 table, but when you look at the #HPD_Temp2 table, it brings back 2.7k records.

If you look at the main insert statement though, it doesn't bring back any.

Records filtered out in temp table
[image: #HPD_Temp3]

Records **not** filtered out in other temp table
[image: #HPD_Temp2]

Main INSERT statement
[image]

Am I filtering something down to much in this sp?

Here is the code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_FactSGIHoldPerDay]
    @CurrentDate NVARCHAR(100) -- Input parameter for the yyyy-MM-dd (e.g., 2024-03-01 for March 1, 2024)

AS -- Start of the stored procedure's code block
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- DECLARE variables
    DECLARE @CurrentMonthBeginDate DATE;
    DECLARE @CurrentMonthEndDate DATE;
    DECLARE @TwoMonthsAgoBeginDate DATE;
    DECLARE @TwoMonthsAgoEndDate DATE;
    DECLARE @ThreeMonthsAgoBeginDate DATE;
    DECLARE @ThreeMonthsAgoEndDate DATE;
    DECLARE @SixMonthsAgoBeginDate DATE;
    DECLARE @SixMonthsAgoEndDate DATE;
    DECLARE @TwelveMonthsAgoBeginDate DATE;
    DECLARE @TwelveMonthsAgoEndDate DATE;

    -- SET variables:
    SET @CurrentMonthBeginDate = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@CurrentDate), MONTH(@CurrentDate), 1);
    SET @CurrentMonthEndDate = EOMONTH(@CurrentMonthBeginDate)
    SET @TwoMonthsAgoBeginDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -2, @CurrentMonthBeginDate) -- 2 Months back
    SET @TwoMonthsAgoEndDate = EOMONTH(@TwoMonthsAgoBeginDate)
    SET @ThreeMonthsAgoBeginDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -3, @CurrentMonthBeginDate) -- 3 Months back
    SET @ThreeMonthsAgoEndDate = EOMONTH(@ThreeMonthsAgoBeginDate)
    SET @SixMonthsAgoBeginDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -6, @CurrentMonthBeginDate) -- 6 Months back
    SET @SixMonthsAgoEndDate = EOMONTH(@SixMonthsAgoBeginDate)
    SET @TwelveMonthsAgoBeginDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -12, @CurrentMonthBeginDate) -- 12 Months back
    SET @TwelveMonthsAgoEndDate = EOMONTH(@TwelveMonthsAgoBeginDate)

-- SELECT 
--      @CurrentMonthBeginDate CurrentMonthBeginDate
--     ,@CurrentMonthEndDate CurrentMonthEndDate
--     ,@TwoMonthsAgoBeginDate TwoMonthsAgoBeginDate
--     ,@TwoMonthsAgoEndDate TwoMonthsAgoEndDate
--     ,@ThreeMonthsAgoBeginDate ThreeMonthsAgoBeginDate
--     ,@ThreeMonthsAgoEndDate ThreeMonthsAgoEndDate
--     ,@SixMonthsAgoBeginDate SixMonthsAgoBeginDate
--     ,@SixMonthsAgoEndDate SixMonthsAgoEndDate
--     ,@TwelveMonthsAgoBeginDate TwelveMonthsAgoBeginDate
--     ,@TwelveMonthsAgoEndDate TwelveMonthsAgoEndDate
  
    -- Aggregate FactSGI data
    IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.#FactSGI_Aggregated') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #FactSGI_Aggregated
    END

    CREATE TABLE #FactSGI_Aggregated
    (
    LocationKey INT, -- Or the appropriate data type
    AggregatedNetFunds NUMERIC(28, 16),
    LocationShare NUMERIC(28, 16)
    );
    INSERT INTO #FactSGI_Aggregated
    SELECT f.LocationKey,
       SUM(NetFunds) AS AggregatedNetFunds,
       SUM(LocationShare) AS LocationShare
    FROM vw_FactSGI f
    INNER JOIN (SELECT LocationKey
                      ,vw.DateKey
                      ,vw.EquipmentKey
                      , CASE
                            WHEN dd.Date >= '2012-01-01' AND dd.Date <= '2019-06-30'
                                THEN CAST(0.3464 * vw.NetFunds AS NUMERIC(28, 16))
                            WHEN dd.Date >= '2019-07-01' AND dd.Date <= '2020-06-30'
                                THEN CAST(0.3314 * vw.NetFunds  AS NUMERIC(28, 16))
                            WHEN dd.Date >= '2020-07-01' AND dd.Date <= '2023-12-31'
                                THEN CAST(0.3257 * vw.NetFunds  AS NUMERIC(28, 16))
                            WHEN dd.Date >= '2024-01-01' AND dd.Date <= GETDATE()
                                THEN CAST(0.3254 * vw.NetFunds  AS NUMERIC(28, 16))
                        ELSE NULL
                        END LocationShare
                FROM vw_FactSGI vw
    INNER JOIN dbo.DimDate dd ON vw.DateKey = dd.DateKey
                WHERE dd.Date BETWEEN @CurrentMonthBeginDate And @CurrentMonthEndDate) f1 
                    ON f.DateKey = f1.DateKey AND f.LocationKey = f1.LocationKey AND f.EquipmentKey = f1.EquipmentKey
    INNER JOIN dbo.DimDate dd1 ON f.DateKey = dd1.DateKey
                WHERE dd1.Date BETWEEN @CurrentMonthBeginDate AND @CurrentMonthEndDate
    GROUP BY f.LocationKey;


    -- Calculate HPD Values and Store in Temp Tables
    SELECT sf1.LocationKey,
           CAST(SUM(sf1.NetFunds) AS NUMERIC(28, 16)) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS NUMERIC(10, 0)) AS HPD_1M
    INTO #HPD_Temp1 
    FROM dbo.vw_FactSGI sf1
    INNER JOIN dbo.DimDate dd ON sf1.DateKey = dd.DateKey
    WHERE Audited = 1 AND dd.[Date] >= @CurrentMonthBeginDate -- Start of 1-month range
                      AND dd.[Date] <= @CurrentMonthEndDate -- End of 1-month range 
    GROUP BY sf1.LocationKey
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 20;

    SELECT sf2.LocationKey,
           CAST(SUM(sf2.NetFunds) AS NUMERIC(28, 16)) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS NUMERIC(10, 0)) AS HPD_2M
    INTO #HPD_Temp2
    FROM dbo.vw_FactSGI sf2
    INNER JOIN dbo.DimDate dd ON sf2.DateKey = dd.DateKey
    WHERE Audited = 1 AND dd.[Date] >= @TwoMonthsAgoBeginDate -- Start of 2-month range
                      AND dd.[Date] <= @TwoMonthsAgoEndDate -- End of 2-month range 
    GROUP BY sf2.LocationKey
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 50;

    SELECT sf3.LocationKey, 
           CAST(SUM(sf3.NetFunds) AS NUMERIC(28, 16)) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS NUMERIC(10, 0)) AS HPD_3M
    INTO #HPD_Temp3
    FROM dbo.vw_FactSGI sf3
    INNER JOIN dbo.DimDate dd ON sf3.DateKey = dd.DateKey
    WHERE Audited = 1 AND dd.[Date] >= @ThreeMonthsAgoBeginDate -- Start of 3-month range
                      AND dd.[Date] <= @ThreeMonthsAgoEndDate -- End of 3-month range 
    GROUP BY sf3.LocationKey
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 80;

    SELECT sf6.LocationKey,
           CAST(SUM(sf6.NetFunds) AS NUMERIC(28, 16)) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS NUMERIC(10, 0)) AS HPD_6M
    INTO #HPD_Temp6
    FROM dbo.vw_FactSGI sf6
    INNER JOIN dbo.DimDate dd ON sf6.DateKey = dd.DateKey
    WHERE Audited = 1 AND dd.[Date] >= @SixMonthsAgoBeginDate -- Start of 6-month range
                      AND dd.[Date] <= @SixMonthsAgoEndDate -- End of 6-month range 
    GROUP BY sf6.LocationKey
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 170;

    SELECT sf12.LocationKey, 
           CAST(SUM(sf12.NetFunds) AS NUMERIC(28, 16)) / CAST(COUNT(*) AS NUMERIC(10, 0)) AS HPD_12M
    INTO #HPD_Temp12
    FROM dbo.vw_FactSGI sf12
    INNER JOIN dbo.DimDate dd ON sf12.DateKey = dd.DateKey
    WHERE Audited = 1 AND dd.[Date] >= @TwelveMonthsAgoBeginDate -- Start of 12-month range
                      AND dd.[Date] <= @TwelveMonthsAgoEndDate -- End of 12-month range 
    GROUP BY sf12.LocationKey
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 350;
    
    -- Main INSERT using the temp tables
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[FactSGIHoldPerDay]
        (
        [Date]
        ,[SCIGamesName]
        ,[DBA]
        ,[Segment]
        ,[IGBNumber]
        ,[RM]
        ,[RMRegion]
        ,[ServiceRegion]
        ,[RouteOperator]
        ,[LengthofContract]
        ,[City]
        ,[LiveDate]
        ,[CurrentTC]
        ,[1M_HPD]
        ,[2M_HPD]
        ,[3M_HPD]
        ,[6M_HPD]
        ,[TTM_HPD]
        ,[NTI]
        ,[LocationShare]
        ,[AccountID]
        ,[AgreementExpirationDate]
        ,[Municipality]
        ,[ServiceTerritoryName]
        ,[PhysicalStreet]
        ,[Zip]
        ,[Priority]
        ,[FinanceRegion]
        ,[PODesignation]
        ,[ParentAccount]
        ,[AgreementOriginalSignedDate]
        ,[AgreementCurrentSignedDate]
        ,[ExtensionSigned]
        ,[Extension1Date]
        ,[Extension2Date]
        ,[Extension3Date]
        ,[Extension4Date]
        ,[CurrentLengthofAgreement]
        ,[IGBEstablishmentType]
        ,[CollectionOffice]
        ,[CollectionRegion]
        ,[AccountRank]
        )
    SELECT
            GETDATE(),
            DL.SCIGamesName,
            DL.DBA,
            DL.Segment,
            DL.LicenseNumber,
            DL.RM,
            DL.RMRegion,
            DL.Region,
            DL.RouteOperator,
            DL.LengthofAgreement,
            DL.City,
            DL.AccelVGTLiveDate,
            DL.CurrentVGTCount,
            agg1.HPD_1M,
            agg2.HPD_2M,
            agg3.HPD_3M,
            agg6.HPD_6M,
            agg12.HPD_12M, 
            figb.NetTerminalIncome, 
            LocationShare,
            DL.Code, 
            DL.AgreementExpirationDate, 
            DL.Municipality, 
            DL.ServiceTerritory, 
            DL.Address, 
            DL.ZipCode, 
            DL.Priority, 
            DL.FinanceRegionFormula, 
            DL.PODesignation, 
            DL.ParentAccount, 
            DL.AgreementOriginalSignedDate, 
            DL.AgreementSignedDate,
            DL.ExtensionSigned, 
            DL.Extension1Date, 
            DL.Extension2Date, 
            DL.Extension3Date, 
            DL.Extension4Date, 
            DL.OriginalLengthofAgreement, 
            DL.IGBEstablishmentType, 
            DL.CollectionOffice, 
            DL.CollectionRegion, 
            DL.AccountRank
    FROM  
            #HPD_Temp1 agg1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN #HPD_Temp2 agg2 
                ON agg1.LocationKey = agg2.LocationKey
            LEFT OUTER JOIN #HPD_Temp3 agg3
                ON agg1.LocationKey = agg3.LocationKey
            LEFT OUTER JOIN #HPD_Temp6 agg6
                ON agg1.LocationKey = agg6.LocationKey
            LEFT OUTER JOIN #HPD_Temp12 agg12
                ON agg1.LocationKey = agg12.LocationKey
            INNER JOIN 
            dbo.DimLocation DL
            ON agg1.LocationKey = DL.LocationKey
            INNER JOIN
            vw_FactSGI sf1
            ON agg1.LocationKey = sf1.LocationKey
            INNER JOIN dbo.FactIGB figb
            ON agg1.LocationKey = figb.LocationKey
            INNER JOIN dbo.DimDate dd
            ON sf1.DateKey = dd.DateKey
            INNER JOIN #FactSGI_Aggregated  fsa
            ON DL.LocationKey = fsa.LocationKey 
END

DROP TABLE #FactSGI_Aggregated
DROP TABLE #HPD_Temp1
DROP TABLE #HPD_Temp2
DROP TABLE #HPD_Temp3
DROP TABLE #HPD_Temp6
DROP TABLE #HPD_Temp12

GO
```

Comment: It's going to be very difficult for someone to try and troubleshoot this for you, since we don't have your database with all of the table structures, and the data contained therein.  My suggestion to you would be to take the final SELECT statement (that you expect to be returning some rows to be inserted) and just remove various JOINs one-by-one, to determine which join is restricting the output of your expected rows.  I can almost guarantee you it is likely one of those joins, with a predicate that is not quite right - but it will take investigation to determine which one(s) are the problem